# Object not found

Tags: windows, xampp

I get this error when i open the address "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/"

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

How can i fix this?
I am using Windows 7 home basic and xampp for Windows .

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install phpMyAdmin first. See the [phpMyAdmin website](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).